# Is there a didmount method for function?

Tags: reactjs

I've looked a lot for that, but never actually found answer for it.
I have a function (not a class) that returns some React.Component and I like using it due to how easy it is to use states. Normally I use classes, but there are some places it just feels better to use a function.

Is there any way to check if the function gets didmounted?
I don't want to create any memory leaks.

Example function:

```
export default function foo() {
    const [bar, setBar] = React.useState(false)
    function looping() {
        <some code with useState>
    }
    return (
        <div>Something</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook:

```
export default function foo() {
  const [bar, setBar] = React.useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('mounted')
    return () => {
      console.log('unmounted')
    }
  }, [])

  function looping() {
    <some code with useState >
  }
  return ( 
  <div>Something </div>
  )
}
```

There's also [useLayoutEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect), which works synchronously.

Comment: How beautifull and easy, and never found this way. Thanks a lot, will accept this as an aswer as soon as I can.